# T-SQL: Dynamic Query by Selected Column in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, t-sql, gridview

I'm trying to modify a stored procedure used in an ASP.NET page.

By default, the stored procedure returns all of the data, which can be overwhelming for employees in the plant.

I want to add a **drop down menu item** for the column name and a **text box** for a value to allow our employees to search the data for their specific items.

What I would like to add is the ability to pass in a Column Name and Column Value to search, similar to the following:

```
DECLARE @colName nVarChar(50), @colValue nVarChar(50)
SET @colName='EmployeeID'
SET @colValue='007135'
SELECT  Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7
FROM    viewNum1
WHERE   ((@colName IS NULL) OR (@colValue IS NULL) OR ('['+@colName+']'=@colValue))
```

If all values passed in (`@colValue` and `@colName`), all records return; however, if I try specifying that `@colName`=**EmployeeID** and `@colValue`='007135' (a value that does exist in the database), no records are returned.

Next is the problem that I am running an old SQL Server 2000 database that does not allow the stored procedure to access the table column names, and the whole technique looks prone to SQL Injection.

Finally, I don't see how to bind my `GridView` control to this and still have the ability to display all records.

How would I write such a filtering stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely not recommend doing this with any critical database.  As it opens you up to easy attacks on your data but since you asked below will do the trick for you:

```
DECLARE @colName nVarChar(50) = NULL;
DECLARE @colValue nVarChar(50) = NULL;

DECLARE @sql = 'SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7 FROM viewNum1 WHERE 1=1 ';

if ISNULL(@colName,'')<>'' AND ISNULL(@colValue,'')<>''
    SET @sql = @sql + ' AND ' + @colName + '=''' + @colValue + '''';


exec(@sql);
```

I would recommend you instead create a proc with nullable parameters for each column as it is safer:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ProcName
    @Column1 as nvarchar(50) = NULL,
    @Column[n] as [dbtype] = NULL
AS
BEGIN

SELECT Column1, Column[n]...
FROM viewNum1
WHERE
((@Column1 IS NULL) OR (Column1 = @Column1))
AND ((@Column[n] IS NULL) OR (Column[n] = @Column[n]))...

END

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to generate the entire SQL string (dynamic sql) if you pass in a column name as a parameter.

And then you use `exec(SQL_STATEMENT)` to execute the sql statement.  BTW I do not recommend doing this.  Here is an example on the dbforums: http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/969925-passing-table-column-name-parameter-stored-procedure.html

Also in your code this part doesn't make much sense `@colValue IS NULL`.  If I am reading this correctly you are stating whether a value is NULL and it never is.

Comment: I've got two conflicting answers, it seems. Justin's stored procedure uses the `@colValue IS NULL`, but you are saying that won't work. I am not refuting anyone; I simply don't know my SQL well enough to know who is correct. You have more rep on here, so I asked you.

Comment: @jp2code - points don't matter - i am just here to help.  Think about it this way..if you wrote code like this `SELECT...FROM..WHERE 123 IS NULL` does that make sense?  You are trying to assign a value to null?  You will want to say `Column IS NULL` and not `VALUE IS NULL`.  BTW look at justins stored procedure he does not use that in his where statement.  My advice is write your sproc like he did using WHERE and boolean expressions like AND / OR but do not use the colval IS NULL portion.

Comment: BTW they are definately not conflicting answers, we are giving the same answer he is just giving you sample code.

Comment: If, in the stored procedure, a `@colName` were not provided (since stored procedures have no overloads), then I would need to check for `@colName IS NULL`.